# how to execute service while getting subscriber messages

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, multithreading

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to build a service to move to a particular point on a line. The problem is when I receive my service call, the thread is stuck in this callback and so global spinner in another thread does not process callback queue. I have read some handy advice in a related [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/53055/ros-callbacks-threads-and-spinning/), however I see no way to use multithreaded or async spinner elegantly in my case.

Omitting some irrelevant details, I have two nodes that give me odometry and expect twist respectively, thus managing an engine. As a backbone of my node I have a software PID regulator, that tells me what speed I should set in twist for a good speed profile based on current goal and current odometry. I used three std::thread's: to run the service's callback, to publish twist on odometry callback and to run spinOnce() with some loop rate. As soon as I stop in service callback (locked by a mutex set in PID regulator until I reach destination), odometry callback is never triggered.

I could implement my own child class from ros::Spinner that could process my service calls asynchronously and all other messages synchronously, but that sounds like overengineering for such a primitive system. What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320054/how-to-execute-service-while-getting-subscriber-messages/) by [volume_8091](https://answers.ros.org/users/39641/volume_8091/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2019-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does [roscpp/Overview/Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) not answer your question(s)?

> I could implement my own child class from ros::Spinner that could process my service calls asynchronously and all other messages synchronously, but that sounds like overengineering for such a primitive system.

Multithreaded or asynchronous spinning should do what you are after.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1